# Variable is not incrementing in C# Release x64

Tags: c#, 64-bit, jit

Could someone explain to me why this piece of code is doing well when I execute it on a x86 platform and why it fail on x64 ?

Results :

- x86 Debug : 12345678910
- x64 Debug : 12345678910
- x86 Release : 12345678910
- x64 Release : 1111111111

If I change something, like removing one of the unused variables, or if I remove the useless for-loop after p_lFirstId++, the strange behavior disappear.

I found that changing "pdb-only" to "full" in my release configuration, it's work again.

If you run the code directly from visual studio, it's doing well too.

Is this a JIT Compiler bug ?

Thank you in advance.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test(null, null, null, 0, 1);            
    }

    public static void Test(
        List<string> liste, List<string> unused1,
        string unused2, int unused3, long p_lFirstId)
    {
        liste = new List<string>();

        StringBuilder sbSql = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
        {
            sbSql.Append(p_lFirstId);
            p_lFirstId++;                

            foreach (string sColonne in liste)
            {

            }

        }

        System.Console.WriteLine(sbSql.ToString());
    } 
}
```

Comment: Clean then rebuild the solution, I would bet for some reason it is hanging onto an old DLL somewhere.

Comment: You found a JIT optimizer bug.  I'm not close to an x64 to check it.  Post this to connect.microsoft.com, do not forget to carefully document what version of .NET you are using.  It otherwise resembles a bug in the jitter for 3.5 (not sp1).

Comment: What happens if you declare a local copy to modify rather than attempting to modify the parameter variable? I guess that wouldn't be conclusive, though, since it sounds like it's a Hiesenbug of sorts.

Comment: I test it with .NET 3.5 and .NET 4. It's the same error.

Comment: Sorry, the rebuild solution is not working ;)

Comment: If I use a local variable to increment, it's work well. However ++p_lFirstId or p_lFirstId = p_lFirstId + 1 are not working.

Comment: This does appear to be a bug.  Using Visual Studio 2010 with .NET 4.0.  Run in Release mode in the debugger, it works correctly.  But run standalone, it fails.

Comment: Yeah this looks like a bug. I was able to recreate it on a Win 7 64 bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the CLR. I would advise contacting Microsoft and asking them to correct this bug in their next release.

Comment: I report it to Microsoft: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/636466/variable-is-not-incrementing-in-c-release-x64